# Batch to stop/run tomcat server when max CPU

Tags: cpu, batch, batch-file, cpu-usage, tomcat

I'm looking for operation system properties that could be used in a batch script on windows, that will stop tomcat services and start them again when the CPU usage of tomcat process reach its maximum value:

```
SET USAGE_TOMCAT = tomcat_service_usage_pourcentage
SET MAX_CPU= 98% of CPU

if USAGE_TOMCAT > MAX_CPU          
 run TOMCAT_DIR/bin/shutdown.bat
 run TOMCAT_DIR/bin/startup.bat
```

In this case, how could USAGE_TOMCAT and MAX_CPU be defined?

Comment: It might be worth looking into a user defined "Data Collector Sets".  You can set one up in Perfmon to monitor a performance counter, e.g. CPU usage of a process.  Once action can be to create an event log entry under: "/Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Diagnosis-PLA/Operational".  You can then create a scheduled task to take action on such an event id for example and add some logic from there.  Maybe see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Maybe also look into Powershell, you can use Get-Counter to get performance data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter

Comment: check logman command.With it you can create tresholds , and when they are reached a task can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

[logman](https://ss64.com/nt/logman.html)  can create alerts that can monitor some system parameters and run a scheduled task. with [shctasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) you can create such task.

```
:: create task that will be executed by logman
SCHTASKS /create /tn "HIGH_CPU" /tr "TOMCAT_DIR/bin/shutdown.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
::Set logman threshold
Logman.exe create alert high_cpu -th "\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time>98" -tn "HIGH_CPU"
```